# Check if string has valid Twig syntax

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Simple, in a Symfony2 app, inside a function of a service class, I want to check if a given string passed as argument has valid Twig syntax...

```
public function checkIfValidTwig($twigString)
{
    $isValid = false;
    $isValid = someWay->toCheckIf()->itIsValid($twigString);
    return $isValid;
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Twig_Environment::tokenize()`, which will throw an exception `Twig_Error_Syntax` if the Twig code cannot be parsed - https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/internals.html#the-lexer

```
class TwigValidator
{
    /**
     * @var \Twig_Environment
     */
    private $twig;

    /**
     * @param \Twig_Environment $twig
     */
    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $twigString
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function checkIfValidTwig($twigString)
    {
        try {
            $this->twig->tokenize($twigString);
        
            return true;
        } catch (\Twig_Error_Syntax $e) {

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create Constraint class, fortunately, you have here the exact procedure described in the context of your problem:

http://labs.octivi.com/validation-constraint-for-twig-template-syntax/